# Grub mismatched names rescue mode

Tags: 14.04, grub2, grubrescue

My VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 wasn't booting properly, and I read somewhere about updating my packages. Along the way Grub got updated and now I am stuck in rescue mode. It says "error: mismatched names".

I have no clue what to do and I can't find anything. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have never done this in Virtual Box, my normal solution is to use the `boot-repair` tool.  According to a few blog posts I found on google, other people were able to use it to repair a linux installation in Virtual Box.

First, boot Virtual Box from an Ubuntu `.iso` file (you can download it from the Ubuntu website).

Then install and run `boot-repair` as in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Restart Virtual Box, and hopefully this fixes your problem!

Comment: boot-repair was a bit odd (for instance, it gave a shell command to install linux at one point, which was unnecessary), but at least my VM starts now! thanks!